# Is there any way or tweak that I can do on Node-RED to open the template and function nodes on an external editor?

Tags: node-red

On Node-RED, when we press `Ctrl+f` and type a word, we can see all nodes that contain that specific word. When I have different nodes carrying code on both function and template nodes, sometimes it'd be useful to open all selected nodes or filtered nodes on an external editor. Just so I'd be able to do some bulk edits on my nodes (even though Node-RED organizes the main idea of the code, I miss the possibility of editing code on multiple nodes at once). In my specific case, I know how to use Vim and how to edit multiple files at once with it. So, is it possible to do on Node-RED? Can I configure Node-RED to open the content of the template and function nodes on an external editor that I have installed on my system?

I know that this functionality would mean that the editor would open outside the browser and it would only work on the computer that I have Node-RED installed. This is the kind of functionality that I would need just sometimes to bulk rename some variables and edit similar blocks of code across different files.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible.

The closest would be a contrib node that supports storing the code in a function node in a separate files. I know it was built but I can't find it on https://flows.nodered.org and I don't think it has been kept up to date with changes/updates to the core function node. It also offers no way to launch an editor to edit those files or a way to trigger a deployment when the files are changed.

Comment: I see... But is there a workaround for the times I want to edit the code that I wrote on multiple nodes at once? Like changing the name of a variable for example? Since it's not possible to edit nodes with an external editor, the only way I can think right now would be exporting my entire flow as JSON, editing it, and importing the new JSON again. I'm not sure if I'm missing something else...

Comment: No, but if you are reusing the exact same function node in multiple places then you should put it in a subflow. That way there is only one place to edit it.

Comment: True, a subflow solves the problem for most cases. But sometimes I have some flow variables that are used on multiple nodes and I want to rename them in order to organize the code better. Clicking on each node for renaming ends up being a log of work depending on the size of my flow and how frequently this variable is used... For these cases, exporting, renaming and importing again is the way to go for me.